# VB.net application asking for Admin rights

Tags: vb.net

Normally, while in the debug my application run without prompting for admin access, but after I move the .exe out to test it out side of the debug it requires admin right. It didn't need to do it before and I didn't change anything between when it started doing this. Is there something that I could change that would fix this?

Comment: If I understood your question properly, you have built an admin-rights app without noticing it; if you change it back to non-admin, you would stop seeing this prompt (also it would stop running under admin-rights-required conditions). Here you have a link with some information on all that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90702/how-does-a-program-ask-for-administrator-privileges

Answer (score 0):

Close visual studio. Find it from all programs, right click and run as Admin. Try that