# Run Program as Administrator in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am programming with vb.net .
I have a program which needs Administrator Privileges

I want:
If program started then a Prompt Show (UAC(User Account Control)) shows that it have to tun as administrator.
Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a program ask for administrator privileges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90674/how-does-a-program-ask-for-administrator-privileges)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following to make sure the program has admin permissions:

You can edit the UAC Settings (in VB 2008), which is located in the Project Settings. Look for the line that says

Change `level="asInvoker"` to:

`level="asInvoker"` (normal account - default)

`level="requireAdministrator` (require administrator - What you need... but could be next one)

`level="highestAvailable"` (if anything is higher then administrator, require that)

Hope it helps :)

-nfell2009

Comment: Hi Thank U For Helping...I have Visual Studio 2012 But I didn't see it in project settings...:http://up.ashiyane.org/images/twrduv0qjamu3mirz8ot.png

Comment: Okay, go into the project settings again, then click the button:
"View Windows Settings" - Then look for the <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />

Comment: OK I saw It...Now What can i do with this line?? <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />Thank you:

Comment: You change the level="asInvoker" to what I said above, level="requireAdministrator or level="highestAvailable"

Comment: I have to change it to<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />???i want that when the program started then a prompt shows...

Comment: Oh it worked? :) Thats good I must have done something wrong lol

Comment: what is the meaning of uiAccess  = false?

Comment: omfg, I almost went bananas.. I'm running VS 2013 and no advice helped, but now I got it working.. Set "requireAdministrator" as described; in the upper toolbar set from "Debug" to "Release"; build the project. Now the binary in your project folder (bin\release) will ask for admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

None of the project settings suggestions worked for me in Windows 10 64 bit.   I changed to Release, I replaced "asInvoker" line with "requireAdministrator" line and still was getting Access Denied Exceptions.  The only way to run thru VS2013 is to run the environment off the bat AS AN ADMINISTRATOR.